# How to estimate the error of a numerical multiple integration

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I'm integrating over the wholes space the function

$$f(\vec{r_1},\vec{r_2})=\exp{\bigg[-(r_{1\alpha}+r_{1\beta}+r_{2\alpha}+r_{2\beta})\bigg]} \cdot 1/r_{12}$$

where $\vec{r_\alpha}=(-R/2,0,0), \vec{r_\beta}=(R/2,0,0)$, $r_{ij}=|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|(i=1,2;j=\alpha,\beta)$ and $R$ is given as a constant. Mathematica is proven to be ineffective for this sort of problem, so I have to manually write a program to calculate this numerically.

My method: As the exponential function decreases rather rapidly, I will set the limits of the integration within $[-5R,5R]$ for each component of $\vec{r_1},\vec{r_2}$. Then I will break the integration interval into $N$ parts with equal length and calculate the integration through summation of rectangles.

But here comes the problem: the function is not monotonous, so the maximal and minimal values of $f$ in the subintervals are not easily obtained. Besides when $\vec{r_1}=\vec{r_2}$ singularity occurs. So how could I determine the error of my numerical integration in this case? Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand the description of your function, can you clarify its definition more precisely, in particular what space you are actually integrating over?

Comment: @Ian $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$ are two vectors in the 3D-Euclidean space, while $\vec{r_\alpha}$ and $\vec{r_\beta}$ are two constant vectors. And I have to integrate $f$ for all $\vec{r_1}=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $\vec{r_2}=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$. So this is actually a sixfold integration. Sorry about the sloppy notation, I'm always a bit fuzzy about it.

Comment: So your problem looks like this. You have two privileged points: $x^* = [-R/2,0,0,-R/2,0,0]$ and $-x^*$. The natural norm on $\mathbb{R}^6$ here is $\| x \| = \left ( \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i \right )^{1/2} + \left ( \sum_{i=4}^6 x_i \right )^{1/2}$. Your exponential term is $e^{-\| x - x^* \|} e^{-\| x + x^* \|}$. So this is $e^{-R}$ on the line segment between $x^*$ and $-x^*$ and then decays exponentially (but anisotropically) as we move away from this line segment. Then there is a singularity at each point in the three dimensional subspace whose elements satisfy $x_1=x_4,x_2=x_5,x_3=x_6$.

Comment: So now you need to figure out how to handle the singularities analytically, which basically means you need to know how to integrate $1/r_{12}$ over a ball. If you can do that, then you can figure out how to split the domain to set up your integration.